# Underdetermined Equation Optimization

Tags: optimization

For the equation:
$$5X + Y + Z = 600$$

With constraints:
$$92 \le X \le 95$$ $$46 \le Y \le 55$$

I want to find a method that will choose values for  $X$ and $Y$ such that $\lvert Z\rvert$ is minimized.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried yourself? If you share your thoughts on the problem, other users will be able to give you a more suitable answer.

Comment: I haven't come across something like this before, so I was hoping to get some key words to search to find solutions to such problems, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $Z=600-5X-Y$

But you want $|Z|=\max(600-5X-Y,5X+Y-600)$

This gives you the two constraints:

$|Z|\ge600-5X-Y$ , which is rewritten as $|Z|+5X+Y\ge600$

$|Z|\ge5X+Y-600$ , which is rewritten as $|Z|-5X-Y\ge-600$

You need to solve the LP:

```
minimise absZ
st
absZ >= 600-5X-Y
absZ >= 5X+Y-600
X <= 95
X >= 92
Y <= 55
Y >= 46
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. For an additional constraint, Z>=0, do you just add this to the list of constaints?

Comment: You can do, although most solvers use the simplex algorithm that assumes all variables are positive unless explicitly declared otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $Z$ we get $$Z = 600 - 5X - Y$$ Notice that to minimize $|Z|$ we need $X$ and $Y$ to be as large as possible (to make the $600$ decrease the most, but not pass $0$ otherwise $|Z|$ will no longer be at a minimum.). So from our constraints we obtain $$X = 95, Y = 55$$